# Are JSON schemas necessary for defining the structure of a JSON?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I am asking this because I see that the current JSON schema draft (http://json-schema.org/) proposes to have the schema of JSON in the following way:

for the JSON :

```
{
 "a":"abc"
 "b": 123
}
```

the schema proposed in the draft is like

```
{
 "type":"object"
 "properties":{
  "a": {"type":"string"}
  "b": {"type":"integer"}
 }
}
```

My question here is does the JSON itself not define its structure? Is a separate schema necessary?

The schema proposed by the draft validates the JSON that have the above structure and those JSON are always of the format

```
{
 "a":"string"
 "b": 1 (or some number)
}
```

So what is the need of a separate schema for JSON. We can simply use the JSON to define its structure also.

PS. I know that we can specify some restrictions on the values that the JSON can take through the schemas proposed in the draft, but from the point of view of defining structure of a JSON, are the proposed schemas necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON itself does not define the structure.  For example, I could write:

```
{
  "a": "string",
  "b": "another string"
}
```

That's also valid JSON - but it's "differently structured" JSON, because `"b"` is now a string.  But your API might only accept JSON with a particular structure, so although it's valid JSON, it's not the shape you need.

Now, do you *need* JSON Schema to define the structure of your JSON data?  No.  You could instead say:

> The value must be an object.  It must have two properties:
>
> - `"a"` - must be a string
> - `"b"` - must be an integer

A programmer could understand this very easily, with no squiggly brackets or anything.

However, there are advantages to having a *machine-readable* description of the format, because it lets you automate various things (e.g. testing, generating documentation, generating code/classes, etc.)

---

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, you can take the type information from some example data, and use that as a model for other data.  In this case, you're basically using your example data as a super-basic schema.

For very simple constraints (basic type), this works.  However, how would you say that `"b"` has to be an integer instead of a float?  How do you say that `"b"` must be > 0?  How do you say that `"a"` must not be the empty string (`""`)?

There are indeed tools that generate a basic JSON Schema from example data - however, the resulting schema usually requires a bit of tweaking to actually describe the format (e.g. min/max, required/optional properties, etc.).

Comment: but looking at the JSON, the type of the quantity is deducible. So I can say JSON instance itself contains the information of the type and the structure

Comment: The type can be deduced in the following way: 
1. If the value has quotes surrounding, it is a string ("abc")
2. If the value is either true/false (without quotes) then it is a Boolean
3. If it is null (without quotes) then it represents null
4. If it is a number/decimal (without quotes) , then it is a numeric type

Comment: Ah, right - so you're talking about checking against example data, instead of a schema?  Fair enough - although how do you tell the difference between an integer/floating-point, or specify minimum length for strings, etc.?

Comment: Added section in answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree that if the need is to specify extra restrictions such as Length of string, or regexes it should match etc. , JSON schemas are necessary. But if only type & structure information is important for me I can go with using the instance itself as a schema right?

Comment: Sure - if you don't need to distinguish between integers and numbers, specify required/optional, etc., then you could just use an example instance instead of a schema.  If the title were "*Is JSON Schema necessary if I only need to say this particular limited set of things*" then the answer is no - but the title isn't very specific, and things like required/optional and integer/number are fairly common constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Until now have never been necessary and in the short term I don't think it gets to be.

I personally like JSON because its simplicity, portability and flexibility.

I don't see even major brands using that schema so until now they don't take its serious.

Comment: Would you consider [Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/1/8/json_schema_for_heroku_platform_api) a major brand? :p

Comment: How about [Google](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using#discovery-doc-resources) (although they use v3)?  They also use JSON Schema for some internal stuff within Chrome.

Comment: in that case its time to look forward schemas, talking about API Its a good practice have defined your entities .

Comment: @cloudfeet can you give me some more systems that you know of which are using JSON schemas so that I could see what they provide. Thanks in advance!